# Is this how I add this anti-spam to my PHP?

Tags: php, forms

Not up on my php the way I should be, thanks for any help...

*I put this in the form html*

```
<p class="antispam">Leave this empty:
<br /><input name="url" /></p>
```

*This in the css*

```
.antispam { display:none;}
```

**The question is the comment part *if the url field is empty* correct for the PHP? 

The {curly} brackets seem out of place to me.**

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = nl2br($_POST['message']);
$todayis = date("l, F j, Y, g:i a") ;
$subject = "Message from Your Website";
$body = "From $name, \n\n$message";
$headers = 'From: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

// if the url field is empty
if(isset($_POST['url']) && $_POST['url'] == ''){

mail("me@my.com", $subject, $body, $headers);

}
?>
<!--My callback -->
<div id="mail_response">
    <h3>Thank you <?php echo $name ?>!</h3><br />
    <p>I will answer your message soon as possible.</p><br /><br /><br />
    <h5>Message sent on: </h5>
    <p><?php echo $todayis ?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Are you asking whether a hidden input is a way to prevent people from sending automated posts to your site? Use a CAPTCHA.

Comment: The "if" php that I commente and put in doesn't look right with the curly { then mail here; then the end curly } so did I do that correct?

Comment: @Gord - the if statement is fine in essence, though it could just be if(empty($_POST['url'])). Whether this is a worthwhile approach to trying to stop spam is a different matter.

Comment: Are you just asking if you're entering correct PHP syntax? Isn't that what the language documentation is for? It explains clearly how to write an `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks Mark, jquery css and html I'm not too bad with but php and forms ugh!

Comment: I made it live and it doesn't work. So there is something wrong with my syntax. MAN! Hate I hate forms.

Comment: the css needs to go either in an included css file (`<link rel='stylesheet' href='/path/to/css'/>`) or in a style tag. that syntax isn't a php thing... is a html/css thing. What this technique does is creates a field that is invisible to humans (via the css display:none style rule) but is likely to be filled in by some kind of bot. So on the PHP side if you see a value in that field you can be pretty confident the form didn't come from a human.

Comment: Hint: This isn't a worthwhile way to fight spam. Robots are not _that_ stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

```
if(isset($_POST['url']) && $_POST['url'] == ''){
    if( mail("me@my.com", $subject, $body, $headers) )
    {
        ?>
            <div id="mail_response">
                <!-- Write html here -->
            </div>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        // something went wrong
    }
}
```

Also, you should not use

```
'Reply-To: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" .
```

because, this is the sender's email address
instead, you can use

```
$headers = 'From: ' . $email . '\r\n' .
'Reply-To: nobody@example.com' . '\r\n' .
'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . '\r\n' .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Also you are not checking the form fields, whether they are empty or not and it's a good practice to **filter the user inputs**.

Also, this is not a good way to fight spams, instead you can use a [captcha](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/09/22/21-free-captcha-sources/).

Comment: That's the answer to a very simple question, thank-you Sheika. I use an ajax callback to keep it on the same page rather than php but that is a good idea to get the email in the reply. Now I can move on to the captcha.